# how to get a 1x4 double from 1x1x4 double?

Tags: matlab

I have a value with the type `1x1x4 double` and need to make a `1x4 double` out of it.

The problem is, I dont know how to do it. Can anybody help me?

It looks like:

```
val(:,:,1) =

    0.5601


val(:,:,2) =

    0.4876


val(:,:,3) =

    0.8146


val(:,:,4) =

    0.6207
```

But it should be:

```
1x4 double = 
    0.5601    0.4876    0.8146     0.6207
```

Comment: post this as an answer and i will accept it, it solved the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get rid of singleton dimensions using the [squeeze](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) function: `squeeze(val)'`

You can also look at [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/reshape.html) or [permute](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) if your problem is a bit more complex

Answer (score 2):

If all the other dimensions are singleton, and the result would be just a 1D vector, you can also use the following:

```
val(:)'
```